# Avoid grouping in regular expressions

Tags: regex

I have the following regular expression for checking the time format *HHMM*

```
([0-1][0-9]|[2][0-3])([0-5][0-9])
```

This works perfect, but now I faced a problem with my application. It requires that the result of the upper expression returns the time in only one group, not in two. Is there a possibility to bundle parts of the regular expression without grouping them?

Thanks in advance ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, use non-capturing parentheses:

```
(?:[01][0-9]|2[0-3])(?:[0-5][0-9])
```

You can of course enclose the entire regex in a capturing group if your app requires at least one group.

Comment: what if we use `\d` instead of `[0-9]`

Comment: @diEcho: It may not mean the same depending on the regex engine. For example, in .NET, `\d` also matches `٣`...